# What the difference between virtualbox-guest-dkms and virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, drivers

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox, after installing guest additions I have a choise between virtualbox-guest-dkms and virtualbox-guest-dkms-hwe. 
What is the difference between them?

[image: Ubuntu update manager]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not an Ubuntu guru, but I believe this has something to do with Ubuntu's HWE (Hardware Enablement) kernel stack. The idea is a rolling-release kernel that can support newer hardware for LTS releases.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

I may be wrong, and I definitely have not performed tests on this, but I suspect that there is little advantage to using the HWE stack in a VBox guest.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so, basically, if I have a potato PC I dont need it? :)